# Preference-heards does not appear

Tags: android

My eclipse does not show preference-headers. I created a new `xml` folder in `res`. I created `preference.xml` in the xml folder. `Preference.xml` files "Preference-PreferenceScreen-SwitchPreference..." but preference-headers doesn't appear. Where is preference-headers?

[Screenshot of dialog missing preference headers](http://i.hizliresim.com/REXX6Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<PreferenceHeader>` XML element.

What you want is a `<PreferenceCategory>`, which will add a header above a group of preferences.

For example, the following will add a header with the contents of a String resource called `R.string.my_prefs_header`:

```
    <!-- Your <Preference /> elements go here -->

</PreferenceCategory>
```

For more information and examples, see [the Settings documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Titles).